# How Do I change the Fields shown when Creating a New Account

Tags: account, new

I want to change the Fields asked for when Users try and create a New Account to very specific fields not related to what they see in their Page layout.
[image]

I read somewhere that it was through creating a record type that has a specific page layout, that somehow only is triggered on the New AccounT?

Can't seem to find that article again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating the **record types** for different account, then assign different page layouts to that particular record types. On page layout, you can add or remove some fields according to your business needs.